# Data processing and video generation with OpenGL/CL

Tags: opengl, opencl, gpu

Goal: compensate and visualize a stream of 14-bit data (2D video).

Existing solution: Each sample needs to be compensated for a gain and offset, so it requires one multiplication and one addition. Then I assign a colour to the sample by a look-up table and output a stream of "colours" directly to the display. Everything is done on CPU.

Requirements: I need to be able to dynamically set a look-up table (palette).

It seems obvious to use GPU for such an operation, but I couldn't find any info about how to move from data domain to picture domain with OpenGL. I've thought about using OpenCL for data compensation and image generation and then moving to OpenGL for displaying (or in general: for manipulating picture).

Can you recommend me a good approach for this? Can this all be efficiently achieved just with the OpenGL? How?

Comment: I need to use OpenGL ES 2.0 which doesn't seem to support a "normal" unsigned short, only GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT_5_6_5, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT_4_4_4_4. I think that any multiplication will treat RGB channels separately which will distort my data.
Do you have a workaround for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it can be done using only OpenGL.

I would suggest a workflow like the following:

For each frame:

1. Upload frame from stream to texture memory
2. Draw a full-screen quad, with texture coordinates from 0,0 to 1,1
3. In a fragment shader apply for each pixel the appropriate transformation. The lookup table can also be stored in a texture, so you only have to perform a lookup on the appropriate location.

In general: This question is at the moment a little bit too broad to be answered in more detail. For example *a stream of 14-bit data* could be a lot of things. I assumed for this answer you meant a (2D) video stream.

Comment: Yes, I meant a 2D video stream. I wanted to emphasise that the input is not a pure video, but something which can not be directly treated as a "colour compatible".
Can the texture be treated as a table of shorts where I can modify element by element, like in C programming? At the level of data I want to avoid colour representation (14 or 16 bit sample instead of 888 RGB).
Can I represent both compensation table (gain and offset for each pixel) and palette as textures? How do I transform data to colours? If I implement lookup table as a texture, can I update it quickly, such as 50 fps?

Comment: You can store the data in a 16bit short texture. If gain and offset are defined per pixel I would also store them in a table, if this are global values, then you should pass them as uniforms to the shader. The transformation from data to color can be done by first reading the data-value from the datatexture, then perform gain and offset correction and use the result as texture address to your palett texture (you might want to keep this texture 1D, then adressing is easier).

Comment: Gain could be somehow constant, offset has to be refreshed on runtime. Do I store them as two textures, one for gain second for offset? How do I multiply and add in texture domain? Can you provide me with a list of keywords (object types, functions etc.) that I should learn about? I'm a total newbie to graphics.

Comment: With constant I meant constant for one frame. You will have to read the general things about textures and shaders. Your workflow will somehow be like the general [workflow for post-processing](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenGL_Programming/Post-Processing)

Comment: Gain and offset are defined per pixel and they have to be updated from time to time. Thanks for your answer!